# Is .net Http Web Request Connection pool per thread or all threads share same pool?

Tags: .net, multithreading, httprequest, connection-pooling, hangfire

Tried to understand how web request connection pool and multi-threads work. The question arise from recent development using Hangfire. We want to limit max number of concurrent out-bound http requests to 10, so we used default connection pool limit which is 10. However, we noticed that we sent more than 10 requests simultaneously, so we think it might has something to do with Hangfire, which created 20 workers.

So the question is what is a Hangfire worker? a thread? Does each worker has its own connection pool? or all works share one connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default number of workers each Hangfire server fires up. This is part of the Hangfire setting ([Documentation on Parallelism](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html))

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 5 };
app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Set workerCount is not an option for us, since it caps other parallel processes too.